# How python2.7 to read load file

Tags: python

I use python2.7 and the script is write in python3.5,and the code is:

```
with open('camera.p', 'rb') as f:
     save_dict = pickle.load(f)
mtx = save_dict['mtx']
dist = save_dict['dist']
```

The error is:

```
KeyError: 'mtx'
```

so how to solve this problem,thank you!

Comment: That's just saying there's no `mtx` key in your dictionary that you unpickled.

Comment: It's completely up to you how to resolve this (e.g. just tell the user the file is invalid, or provide some default/guess if it makes sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the key `mtx` does not exist in the un-pickled `save_dict`.

If you can use a default value for `mtx`, you can use the `dict.get` function:

```py
mtx = save_dict.get('mtx', 'my default value')

# or check if the key exists
if 'mtx' in save_dict:
    process_value(save_dict['mtx'])
```

I recommend opening the `python` repl in a terminal and inspecting the object there. For example:

```sh
# In the terminal
$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 23 2017, 14:40:12)
[GCC ...]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Now inside the python repl, you can execute your code line by line:

```py
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('camera.p', 'rb') as f:
...     save_dict = pickle.load(f)
...
>>> type(save_dict)
<class 'dict'>
>>> save_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['foo', 'bar', 'x'])
```

This will give you a better sense of why the `mtx` key is unexpectedly missing from the `save_dict`.